# Как создать popup menu в связке: IUP + Lua?

Tags: lua

За основу взял пример `"menu"` из папки `examples`, никаких проблем при переделке под свои нужды нет, хочу добавить всплывающее меню по правому клику.
Справка подсказывает:

> "A popup menu is displayed for the user using the IupPopup function (usually on the mouse position) and disappears when an item is selected."

Пока проблему не решил. Просьба минимальный рабочий пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идея в том, чтобы создать обыкновенное меню, но не привязывать к окну. В нужный момент времени просто вызывать функцию `popup` этого меню.

```
require("iuplua")

cv       = iup.canvas {size="300x100", xmin=0, xmax=99, posx=0, dx=10}
dlg       = iup.dialog{iup.frame{cv}; title="IupCanvas"}

mnu = iup.menu
{
  iup.submenu
  {
    iup.menu
    {
      iup.item{title="IupItem 1 Checked",value="ON"},
      iup.separator{},
      iup.item{title="IupItem 2 Disabled",active="NO"}
    } 
    ;title="IupSubMenu 1"
  },
  iup.item{title="IupItem 3"},
  iup.item{title="IupItem 4"}
}


function cv:button_cb(button, pressed, x, y, status)
    local _, _, screen_x, screen_y = string.find(self.SCREENPOSITION, "(%d+),(%d+)")
    if button == 51 and pressed == 0 then
        mnu:popup(tonumber(screen_x) + x, tonumber(screen_y) + y)
    end
end

dlg:showxy(iup.CENTER,iup.CENTER)

if (iup.MainLoopLevel()==0) then
  iup.MainLoop()
  iup.Close()
end
```